# Matlab: remove matrix rows that contain complex numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, complex-numbers

I have a 2 column, N rows matrix. Column 2 contains only real numbers, column 1 contains a mix of real and complex (real+imaginary) numbers. I.e. it is of the following form:

```
14.3 + 0i     27.1 + 0i
3.1 + 1.3i    12.0 + 0i
1.2 + 0i      -11.9 + 0i
0.1 - 3.3i    12.6+ 0i
```

I would like to remove every ROW from the matrix, where the first element of that row (i.e. the column 1 element) contains a complex number, leaving only rows with real numbers in them.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to find all elements of the first column with imaginary part of zero. You keep the corresponding rows and you're finished.

```
B = A(imag(A(:,1)==0),:);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[14.3 + 0i     27.1 + 0i;
   3.1 + 1.3i    12.0 + 0i;
   1.2 + 0i      -11.9 + 0i;
   0.1 - 3.3i    12.6+ 0i];
ind = a == real(a);
newa = a(ind(:,1),:);
```